# Java: My compiler says that one of my printf statements is broken and I can't figure out why

Tags: java

This is my first time asking a question, so sorry if this looks weird.
This is my full code. And the separated line with stars is the line that's breaking.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CashRegister
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        double price;
        final double TAX_RATE = 0.085;
        final double SURCHARGE = 0.04;
        final int MAX_PRICE = 500;
        double addedSurcharge = 0;
        do
        {
            do
            {
                System.out.print("Cost of Item (enter 0 or negative value to exit; max is $500.00): ");
                price = keyboard.nextDouble();
            } while (price > 500);
            int dollars = (int) price;
            int cents = (int) price - dollars;
            int convertPrice = (dollars * 100) + cents;
            if (convertPrice < 1500)
            {
                addedSurcharge = (convertPrice * SURCHARGE) / 100;
                System.out.printf("Surcharge of $%.2f added.", addedSurcharge);
                System.out.println();
            }
            double withTax = ((convertPrice * TAX_RATE) / 100) + addedSurcharge + convertPrice;

        **System.out.printf("Amount due (with 8.5% tax): $%.2f", withTax);**

        System.out.println();
    } while (price > 0);
    System.out.println("Done.");
}
```

Comment: `System.out.printf("Amount due (with 8.5%% tax): $%.2f", withTax);` Change % to %%

Comment: Use `%%` to indicate a percent symbol.

Comment: As a side note, `int cents = (int) price - dollars;` will  yield 0 even if the user enters a double amount.

Comment: Oh wow, that was incredibly fast. Thanks, I had no idea that you needed 2 percent signs in a printf.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape percent signs used as percent signs: `8.5%%` instead of `8.5%`

Comment: It's `%%` not ```\%```

Comment: Fixed in the answer. You can tell I don't use printf that often,